# Программа зависает по непонятным причинам

Tags: c++, c++builder, visual-c++, c++11

Функция:

```
void risuem(double x[50], double y[50], double R[50], int j)
{


    while (j < 49)
    {
        double x1 = x[j];
        double x2 = x[j+1];
        double y1 = y[j];
        double y2 = y[j+1];
        double r1 = R[j];
        double r2 = R[j+1];

        double d = ( x1 - x2 ) * ( x1 - x2 ) + ( y1 - y2 ) * ( y1 - y2 );

        if ( d <= ( r1 + r2 ) * ( r1 + r2 ) && d >= ( r1 > r2 ? r1 - r2 : r2 - r1 ))
        {
            Form1->Image1->Canvas->Pen->Color=clGreen;
            Form1->Image1->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlue;
            Form1->Image1->Canvas->Pen->Width=4;
            Form1->Image1->Canvas->Ellipse(x[j] - R[j], y[j] - R[j], x[j] + R[j], y[j] + R[j]);
        }
        else
        {
            Form1->Image1->Canvas->Pen->Color=clYellow;
            Form1->Image1->Canvas->Brush->Color=clRed;
            Form1->Image1->Canvas->Pen->Width=1;
            Form1->Image1->Canvas->Ellipse(x[j] - R[j], y[j] - R[j], x[j] + R[j], y[j] + R[j]);
        }

        //Form1->Image1->Canvas->Ellipse(x - R, y - R,x + R,y + R);
                            //   x1    y1    x2    y2
    }
}
```

Используем:

```
double arrX[50];
double arrY[50];
double arrR[50];
int i = 0;
if (coutLines != 0)
{      
    while (i < coutLines)
    {              // while (i < coutLines)
        UnicodeString XX = file->Strings[i]; 
        double posX = readCoord(XX, "x");
        double posY = readCoord(XX, "y");
        double posR = readCoord(XX, "R");


        arrX[i] = posX;
        arrY[i] = posY;
        arrR[i] = posR;
        risuem(arrX, arrY, arrR, i);
```

В функции `risuem` проверяем - пересекаются ли окружности. При запуске программы - она просто виснет и её приходиться убивать, используя Диспетчер Задач. Вот значения, откуда берутся данные:

- x=0; y=0; R=50;
- x=0; y=60; R=50;
- x=0; y=120; R=50;
- x=0; y=190; R=50;
- x=60; y=0; R=50;
- x=120; y=60; R=50;
- x=190; y=120; R=50;
- x=250; y=190;R=50;
- x=2500; y=1900; R=50;

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что он вызван банальной опечаткой и вряд ли пригодится будущим посетителям.

Comment: @dizballanze "Floating point overflow. Дело в том, что я проверял значение - всё считает, всё хорошо (в VS). Значит, ошибка где-то тут у меня"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде есть цикл

```
while (j < 49)
{
    ...
}
```

Так вот, судя по коду, j нигде внутри цикла не изменяется.. Этот цикл выполняется бесконечно... Отсюда и кажущееся "зависание".

Предположительно перед концом цикла не хвает чего-то банального вроде

```
j++;
```

Ну и как правильно указал **aratj** - второй цикл тоже бесконечен.

Comment: да, я смотрю в обоих циклах while не инрементируются значения.

Comment: @aratj , и правда так. )

Comment: О боги, просто невнимательность. Спасибо. Сейчас выскакивает ошибка: Floating point overflow. Дело в том, что я проверял значение - всё считает, всё хорошо (в VS). Значит, ошибка где-то тут у меня...

Comment: @aratj, со вторым циклом всё в порядке. Я просто имел смелость "вырвать" кусок кода, где я использую _risuem_ .